# Using <sub> tag and preserve line-height

Tags: html, css

I have a long text with some subscripts and superscripts tags. Example:

```
<div>hello <sub>world</sub>, how are you? Translated as logical aggregates or associative compounds, these characters have been interpreted as combining two or more pictographic or ideographic characters to suggest a third meaning.</div>
```

Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/BzqFb/

Now I can see that lines of text with  text are wider then those without  text. Is there any way how I can change  tag style css and have all lines of text with exactly same height?

And are there some kind of texts which can change height of line in HTML text?

EDIT: I want to have subscript behaviour, not just small text. I can make line-height large so that subscript text should fit the line, but still the line with subscripted text is wider then line without subscripted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `sub` element at all. Instead, use e.g. `<span class=sub>...</span>` together with a style sheet that makes the content vertically lowered and, if desired, sets the font size. For vertical lowering, you can use `position: relative` and a suitable value for `top` or `bottom`; this makes the content displaced without affecting spacing between lines. For example,

```
.sub { position: relative; top: 0.8ex; font-size: 75%; }
```

You could instead use the `sub` element and nullify its effect on vertical placement, with `vertical-align: baseline`, but then you would have difficulties with setting the font size in a cross-browser way, due to a gross IE bug (in interprets a percentage in the `font-size` value for `sub` as relative to the default size it uses for that element, instead of correctly relating it to the parent element’s font sie, as other browsers do).

Note: The `sub` element does not change `line-height`, but it typically makes the height of line boxes larger. This is why you cannot solve the problem by setting `line-height`.

Comment: `Do not use the sub element at all` I do not agree, `<sub>` element is more semantic than `<span>`.

Comment: @Mimi, there is no clue in the question about any specific “semantics”, and the “semantics” of `sub` is just idle talk—and, most importantly, the implementations of `sub` are defective, making the element useless (except for cases where you really don’t care about the quality of rendering).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way how I can change tag style css and have all lines of
>   text with exactly same height

Why just you don't use `<small>` element? it keeps the text vertically aligned with the same line height:

```
<div class="container">hello <small>world</small>, how are you? ...</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/BzqFb/1/)**

Per Original Poster's comment, you could use `position: relative;` for the subscript element and set a `top` of `0.2em` to preserve the line height of the whole text:

```css
sub {
    vertical-align: text-bottom; /* <-- Reset the user agent stylesheet   */
    position: relative;          /* <-- Set position to the element       */
    top: .2em;                   /* <-- Move the <sub> element down a bit */
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/BzqFb/10/)**

Comment: Good job finding a forgotten tag. I thought it was deprecated and found I was wrong after looking at HTML4.01 and HTML5 DTD.  
OP's use is exactly why this tag exists!

Comment: I dont need smaller text, I need subscript without change of line-height.

Comment: Best answer, but still there is a small difference in pixels (height of whole container), but for my use its good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) CSS property like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzqFb/5/)

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Remember, subscript tag makes the text to appear as a subscript of current line. By default `vertical-align:sub;` property is set on sub tags. So either over-ride that or don't use sub tags if you just want to make the text smaller.

**Edited After Question was edited**

It is not the case that subscripted line is wider than any other line. Its just that next word in line could not fit the remaining width available in current line so the word goes to new line.See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzqFb/8/) to validate this point or you can also use `text-align: justify` to make all the lines justified. See this [JsFiddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/BzqFb/9/)

Comment: It does't work, line with <sub> tag is 5 px wider then the rest.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so well. When i look at all your examples in my browser (Chrome on Mac), I see that container element has 5 lines and height 155px. If there was not a sub tag, height would be 150px. I want to have container tag 150px even with <sub> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this

```
sub {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

but the text is almost like normal. http://jsfiddle.net/BzqFb/7/

you might as well use a span and change the span font size to a smaller font