# Height difference divs with `position: relative;` and smaller font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I asked this question about sub tag:

[Using <sub> tag and preserve line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679699/using-sub-tag-and-preserve-line-height)

So now i use `position: relative;` and smaller font to "emulate" behaviour of subscript. But I have found that this solution is not pixel perfect. `<div>` with this emulated sub tag can have bigger height then `<div>` without this emulated sub tags, even when texts in each line line of divs are exactly the same. I observed this behaviour in Chrome and Firefox, here is the problem shown on live code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FRkQ6/

On my Chrome browser in Mac the output is:

```
Height of first div is: 163
Height of first div is: 162
```

This live code works on chrome on mac where both divs have the same lines with same text. On Firefox this demo does not work, because texts in lines are differently rendered. But the problem is similar to Chrome.

Can somebody explain me this behaviour? Is it some bug in browsers or intended behaviour? Can I fix that somehow with CSS (if i subtract height of top and bottom border, which is 2, height should be divisible by line-height, which is 20 in my demo, so I should never get height of 163)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the span is position:relative the browser is still (wrongly) considering its line height.  Adding a line height of zero fixes it...

```
line-height: 0;
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/FRkQ6/1/)**